# Format a text box as a number in a report

Tags: ms-access

I have a text box, FuelGal, in a report which has a calculated value,

```
=FuelLb/6
```

Where FuelLb is another text box in the same report. In the report, the property of FuelGal is set to General Number, and the allowed decimals is set to 1.  When the report is generated, the value is correct, but not limited to one decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the *Format* property of the textbox in the report to: 0.0